# Does Microsoft Azure support SCIM provisioning 1.1?

Tags: azure, single-sign-on, provisioning

I can see in the Microsoft documentation that Microsoft Azure supports SCIM provisioning 2.0. There is no mention of version 1.1. Does Azure support SCIM 1.1 as well?

Microsoft Documentation that I've reviewed: (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/use-scim-to-provision-users-and-groups)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, Azure does not support **SCIM 1.1**.

For more details about the implementations of SCIM 2.0 and SCIM 1.1, refer to the links:

- [SCIM 2.0 Implementations](http://www.simplecloud.info/#Implementations2)

[image]

- [SCIM 1.1 Implementations](http://www.simplecloud.info/#Implementations1)